# Apply dot product to all columns in a 3D array

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I have a 3D array, which I need to transform in one direction. I have a matrix `map_y` that contains the transformation in one direction which I apply using `np.dot`. Is it possible to avoid the nested `for` loop in the code below?

```
import numpy as np

nx, ny, nz = 64, 32, 24
nyc = 11

a = np.random.rand(nz, ny, nx)

ac = np.empty((nz, nyc, nx))

map_y = np.random.rand(nyc, ny)

# Can we do this in a single numpy function?
for k in range(nz):
    for i in range(nx):
        ac[k,:,i] = np.dot(map_y, a[k,:,i])
```

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you?

Comment: It worked out great. I wasn't aware of the `einsum` functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
ac = np.einsum('ijk,lj->ilk',a,map_y)
```

Bit of `einsum` explanation on the problem :

The axes could be thought as schematically, like so -

```
a      : i      x j x k
map_y  :     l  x j
output : i x l      x k
```

Hence, `j` is aligned and also sum-reduced for the output, while the rest are "speard-out", giving us the desired output.

For more info, please refer to the linked docs.

Also, play around with the `optimize` flag in `np.einsum` by setting it as `True` to use BLAS.

Comment: Can you explain the first argument of `einsum` a bit more in detail?

Comment: The string of `einsum` almost writes itself if you map `nz, ny, nx, nyc` on to `i,j,k,l`.  They are the indices for the respective dimensions of `a` and `map_y` (and `ac`).

Comment: @Chiel Added some explanation.